# Why are memory locations also called registers?

Tags: embedded, cpu-registers, memory-mapped-io

In embedded systems and systems programming, the term register is used to refer to

1. a CPU register inside the micro-controller, e.g. R1, R2, PC in ARM micro-controllers, and
2. certain 'special' locations inside memory address space.

Is there a reason or history behind the term 'register' being overloaded this way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Functionally speaking, a register is an element (such as a multi-bit array of D-type flop flops or equivalent) where you can store a value.

In addition to the traditional CPU registers used to hold operands and results from ALU computations, there can be **Special Function Registers** (on-chip or off) dedicated to other purposes.  For example, a UART peripheral implementing a serial port probably has a register to hold the divisor which derives the baud rate from its clock, one for the outgoing data, one for the received data, and one that is a bitmap of mode settings.

On a machine with **Memory-mapped I/O** special function register appear in memory space and are accessed with memory access instructions (though sometimes there are constraints, such as only a particular width of access being legal).  In contrast, on an **I/O mapped** machine, there are special instructions just for accessing I/O port addresses, and (at least on a dual purpose external bus) a control signal which indicates if an access is to memory or I/O space.

Further confusing things, there are a few legacy processor designs like the 8051 where the CPU registers can also be accessed as ordinary memory locations.  And in many other machines, while CPU registers are stored in a register file rather than memory, they functionally have "addresses" in a bitfield of the instruction word, which specifies which register is an operand or result - RISC architectures with their numbered registers make this particularly obvious.

Comment: Great overview. Also wanted to mention that microchip PICs refer to all on-chip data memory as "registers", where most architectures would call it RAM.  This further overloads the term and adds to confusion even more.  Though PICs are generally weird just by being Harvard arch instead of Von Neumann.

Answer (score 2):

I/O or *special-function registers* are typically *memory mapped* but they remain *registers* in the sense that they are not general-purpose memory, but rather I/O peripheral control and status registers.

Unlike memory-mapped random-access read/write or read-only memory, registers typically possess characteristics such as defined power-on/reset states, and may be r/w, r/o, or w/o at the individual bit level.  Further their values may change independently of any value written to them as they are also writeable by the associated peripheral; this is most often reciprocal - the processor writes while the peripheral reads, or vice-versa; often at the bit level rather than the word level. It is even common that a single address can refer to two registers, one read-only, and the other write-only.

Answer (score 1):

Both are registers, that is some little chunk of memory with a special purpose. CPU registers are (naturally) not memory mapped, since they can be accessed with CPU instructions. While registers controlling peripheral hardware outside the CPU core are generally mapped at specific addresses.

So simply put, the only real difference between 1. and 2. is how you access them. But there are all kinds of registers: CPU registers can be quite specialized things related to a given hardware, and not necessarily just general-purpose "accumulators" meant to hold results of the program's calculations.

The wikipedia page for [processor registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register) looks like pretty good reading on this topic.